# Center entire blockquote

Tags: html, css

Currently the text in my blockquotes are centered, but it's creating a problem when there's not a lot of text to quote and the left border ends up too far away from the text.

[Example](http://oi44.tinypic.com/2ns25ux.jpg)

I'd like the border to always be 5px from the text (usually centered under an image on my blog).

Is there any way to center the *entire* blockquote, including the left border, so it isn't stuck in one position while the text is the only thing centered?

Current CSS:

```
blockquote {
    max-width:390px;
    color: #5c4c40;
    text-align: center; 
    border-left: 3px solid #897860; 
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px; 
}
```

Comment: Can you include a screenshot or a drawing of what you want?

Comment: Could you profvide a full example at http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @kmxe060: blockquotes are block-level elements and therefor use the available width. If the blockquote has 500px available space, it will expand to 500px width. You could try around with float/display:inline-block.

Comment: @Pete: It'll stretch to the set max-width then – no matter how many text is inside.

Answer (score 7):

Add  `width:auto;` and `display:table`

```
blockquote {
    max-width:390px;
    color: #5c4c40;
    text-align: center; 
    border-left: 3px solid #897860; 
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:red;
    width:auto;
    display:table
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KYdnJ/32/)**

Comment: That worked, @Sowmya, thanks a lot. Only problem is now the border height has expanded.

Comment: @kmxe060 there might be conflict in your page css. Can you share the page link

Comment: @kmxe060: This appears either to be a padding or line-height issue with conflicting css rules.

Comment: @kmxe060 that height is because of p tag rendered inside the blockquote. Remove the  p tag it wil be fine.

Comment: Ah, I should have noticed that. Thanks. Any ideas on reducing the top & bottom padding?

Comment: you can reduce the space by adding this class blockquote p{  margin:0; padding:0}

Comment: Unfortunately Tumblr automatically renders the <p> and although adding the extra class fixes the spacing problem around the blockquote, it creates another by removing the spacing between paragraphs within the blockquote. 

If inline-block didn't change the spacing, it would work perfectly.

It's starting to look as though I should just leave it as it was and try to avoid quoting small snippets of text.

Comment: Worked but it makes no sense. Why  `display: table` props? It even isn't a table.

Answer (score 3):

```
<center><blockquote>test test test</blockquote></center>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5g0aa3ea/

Comment: Not sure about the status of 'center' back when this answer was given, but as of 2018, the 'center' tag is deprecated. Please don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KYdnJ/34/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="quote">
    <blockquote>some random text</blockquote>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.quote {
    text-align:center;
}

blockquote {
    padding:10px 5px;
    border-left:3px solid #ccc; 
    display:inline-block;
    color:#666;
    background:#eee;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @seemly. Works, but gives me the same height issues as the previous code.